# C++ Shared Objects using STL causes SIGSEGV on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll, g++

I'm writing a simple web server in C++ with support for GET. To support dynamic content, I'm going to make dynamic objects to acts as the program. I.e. requests for URLs like `example.com/dynamicContent/124` will be sent to the `dynamicContent.dll`.

The modules must implement the following function:

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) int handle_request(http::request*, http::response*);
```

I can get a prototype to work fine, but when I try to use `std::string`, the program crashes.
Since the `http::response` API contains methods for setting content/content type etc., and expect string objects, I'm really frustrated.

The modules are compiled with the exact same g++ version as the web server, on the same computer. Here's the Makefile for my testing module:

```
g++ -c modules/TestModule.cpp
g++ -g -Wall -o modules/dynwindows.dll TestModule.o libsol.a
g++ -g -Wall -o dynamic_windows.exe dynamic_windows.cpp libsol.a
```

`libsol.a` is a library with the implementations of `http::request` and `http::response`.

Here's the function:

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) int handle_request(http::request* request, http::response* response)
{
    std::string name = "yo"; // this handle sigsegv
    response->set_status(200);
    response->set_body(name);
    return 1;
}
```

**UPDATE**
The following make makes things work.. Any guesses why?

```
g++ -shared -g -o modules/dynwindows.dll \
-Wl,--export-all-symbols \
-Wl,--enable-auto-import \
-Wl,--whole-archive TestModule.o \
-Wl,--no-whole-archive libsol.a
```

Comment: I guess can't say much without knowing what code/line triggers the seg fault.

Comment: Sharing C++ classes, especially Standard classes such as `std::string`, across DLL boundaries is really asking for trouble.  It's really easy to violate the One-Definition-Rule and land in the realm of undefined behavior.  (This is a significant difference between Windows, where the compiler supplies the standard library, and Linux, where there's a system-wide shared standard library.  Using gcc on Windows does not make this better.)

Comment: @BenVoigt Is there any solution to this problem? Compile everything on the same machine with same gcc with same settings?